# MouseClicked Dilemma

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener

Is it possible to create a if statement questioning if a user has clicked an image using the java method **mouseClicked**?  If so how?
This is what I was thinking would be correct

```
public void mouseClicked(parameters of image){
//Sample Code
}
```

Comment: The answer is "Yes", the problem is, there's not enough context. How is the picture rendered on the screen? Via a JLabel or custom painting? Do y to ignore the image's alpha content (so only the solid part of the image can be clicked)?

Comment: this has nothing to do with c++ or php

Comment: @Dagon: he apparently is ignoring your comment because he did just the same thing with his next question.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to view an image, it must be loaded and placed on a Component (JPanel, JLabel, etc.) right? I'm assuming here since you made no mention of custom painting and provided no code. So just add a MouseListener to whichever Component has the image:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();

// add the image to the label, then:

label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
  {
    System.out.println("Image was clicked!");
  }
});
```